# TextBlob 0-Values for Polarity and Subjectivity

Tags: nltk, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am using TextBlob with python 3 to create sentiment values for a larger corpus of documents. I reviewed the distribution of polarity and subjectivity values and noticed a big share of values equal "0", see the distribution in the image (for polarity values on 1300 documents). I thought this might just be because TextBlob returns 0 as a default value if it wasnt able to calculate the sentiments right or for some other reason. I didnt find any docu on that, but maybe one of you can tell me where the high amount of zeros might origin in.

Best, Nero 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way polarity and subjectivity are defined in textblob, you can follow the following link:

https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/eb08c120d364e908646731d60b4e4c6c1712ff63/textblob/en/en-sentiment.xml

Basically, the lexicon referred by Textblob is en-sentiment.xml.